# Transfer file from a linux machine to a windows machine

Tags: windows, linux, file-transfer

Im on my windows machome at home and i've ssh'ed into my linux machine at work via PuTTY.

I need to transfer 4 text files from the linux machine to my windows machine.

Does anybody know the process to transfer the files over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

> pscp user@server:/path/to/file c:\temp

After that it should ask for the password for user. You can also use wildcard if the four files are in the same folder.

Comment: Is that the right way round? As in from a linux machine to a windows machine?

Comment: You are correct Harpal. I misread the title. Thanks and corrected.

Comment: No problem, Got a pscp command not found error though

Comment: pscp.exe should be in your Putty installation folder. Maybe it isn't on your path. Maybe you used some sort of custom or minimal install?

Comment: Download pscp.exe from http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html and try the command.

Comment: still no luck get still get a "-bash: pscp: command not found"

Comment: Try specifying the path to pscp. Like this: c:\program files\putty\pscp" user@server:/path/to/file c:\temp

Comment: Tried that aswell still get a error. I typed in "scp hsahota@kiev:/home/hsahota/Documents/ProjectI/Project_files/jura_data/A1_B1_100000.txt c:\Users" and got this error: "ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known"

Comment: Are you doing this through cmd or putty? Use the command in cmd instead. Specify path or cd to it then run the command again.

Comment: Glad that worked for you.

Comment: yeah, thx for the help, it was mainly me be stupid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a GUI, you should consider [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/). It's a bit to much for only 4 files. But I'm sure you will use it more than once, once it is installed.